# How to retrieve data and display from database where id = random number?

Tags: sql, vb.net

trying to display data from my database where the id equals to a previously generated number, unfortunately I recieve an error which says 'unknown column q1 in where clause'. The database table has 3 columns, idtopic1, question, answer. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub ViewBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ViewBtn.Click
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root99;database=database"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Dim rndnum As Random
    Dim q1 As Integer
    rndnum = New Random
    q1 = rndnum.Next(1,5)
    Dim q1display As String

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select question from database.topic1 where idtopic1= q1"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        q1display = Convert.ToString(COMMAND.ExecuteScalar())
        q1box.Text = q1display

        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
   End Sub
   End Class
```

Comment: I still receive an error, now it says : 'There is already an open datareader associated with this connection which must be closed first.' I have no clue what this means, I don't see any previous connections.

Comment: I have solved it, query = "select question from database.topic1 where idtopic1= '" & q1 & "'" , also remove all READER statements.

Answer (score 2):

Change following line:

```
Query = "select question from database.topic1 where idtopic1= q1"
```

To:

```
Query = "select question from database.topic1 where idtopic1= " & q1
```